# Does $\int_0^\pi f(x) \, dx \geq 0$ imply $\sup_x (f(x)) \geq 0$??

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For a continuous $f:(0,\pi)\to \mathbb R$, does $\int_0^\pi f(x) \, dx \geq 0 \Rightarrow \sup_x (f(x)) \geq 0 $ ?

I think yes, but I would like to know if I am correct?

Comment: $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is always $\geq 0$.

Comment: @MartinR sorry i mean $sup_x (f(x)) \geq 0$

Comment: I think you right. If $\sup f(x) <0$, then $f(x) <0$. So,...

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 2):

The statement in your (edited) question is correct, and you can easily prove
it by contraposition.

If  $s := \sup_x (f(x)) < 0$ then $f(x) \le s$ for all $x \in (0, \pi)$
and therefore $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \, dx \le \int_{0}^{\pi} s \, dx = s \, \pi < 0$.